# Как найти закрашенную ячейку в Excel файле и извлечь ее содержимое при помощи пакета xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.x, xlsx

У меня есть таблица, в ней много ячеек с данными. У некоторых ячеек цвет, допустим желтый.

Как можно найти эти цветные ячейки и узнать, что они содержат?

Comment: Теоретически можно, но нужно или хорошая библиотека, или хорошо владеть обработкой xml.

Answer (score 6):

Пример с использованием `openpyxl` (работает с `.XLSX` файлами).

Исходный файл:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('c:/temp/a.xlsx')
sh = wb['Sheet1']


print('background colors for ALL cells:\n')
for row in sh.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print(f'[{cell.coordinate}]: {cell.fill.fgColor.value}', end=' ')
    print()

def find_cells_by_color(sh, color='00000000'):
    ret = {}
    for row in sh.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.fill.fgColor.value == color:
                ret[cell.coordinate] = cell.value

    return ret

res = find_cells_by_color(sh, color='FFFFFF00')
print(f'given color has been found in the following cells: {res}')
```

---

Вывод:

```
background colors for ALL cells:

[A1]: 00000000 [B1]: 00000000 [C1]: 00000000
[A2]: FFFFFF00 [B2]: 00000000 [C2]: FFFF0000
[A3]: 00000000 [B3]: FFFFFF00 [C3]: FFFFFF00
[A4]: 00000000 [B4]: 00000000 [C4]: FF00B050

given color has been found in the following cells: {'A2': 1, 'B3': 5, 'C3': 6}
```

PS я не нашел простого способа определить код цвета по наименованию, поэтому пошел эмпирическим путем...

Comment: Интересно, там цвет в aRGB или RGBa? Предполагаю, что все-таки aRGB

Comment: @gil9red, не знаю... Я до этого момента не сталкивался с aRGB и RGBa ;-)

Comment: Ну, RGB -- FF0000, т.е. R=FF, G=00, B=00. А `a`, т.е. альфа-канал указывает какая прозрачность будет у цвета

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, теперь понятно почему там четыре 16-ричных числа, а не три

Answer (score 3):

Для ОС Windows через COM объект это удобнее всего сделать, и не надо дополнительных библиотек и модулей тянуть, Python + VBA:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(u'D:\\xl.xlsx')
sheet = wb.ActiveSheet

var = 0
for row in range(1, 5):
    for column in range(1, 5):
        # Поиск по индексу цвета ColorIndex. Если по цвету, то Color
        if sheet.Cells(row, column).Interior.ColorIndex == 6: 
            var += sheet.Cells(i, j).Value
print(var)

wb.Save()
wb.Close()
Excel.Quit()
```

Comment: `не надо дополнительных библиотек и модулей тянуть` но только на windows и будет работать :)

Comment: О типе оси в вопросе ничего не было, так что тоже имею право

Comment: А я не писал, что права нет, просто могли бы добавить и ограничения, а не только плюсы :)

Comment: Резонное замечание

Answer (score 1):

Можно c помощью `xlrd` проходить по всем ячейкам, получать их цвет и искать нужный с помощью `if`:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("sample.xls", formatting_info=True)
sheets = book.sheet_names() 
for index, sh in enumerate(sheets):
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(index)
    rows, cols = sheet.nrows, sheet.ncols
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            xfx = sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
            xf = book.xf_list[xfx]
            bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index #Цвет фона
            rgb = book.colour_map[bgx] #Цвет в RGB формате
            thecell = sheet.cell(row, col)      
            print thecell.value #Значение данной ячейки
```

Comment: это будет работать для .XLSX файлов?

Comment: @MaxU, да, будет.

Comment: для .XLSX: дает ошибку: `NotImplementedError: formatting_info=True not yet implemented`

Comment: @NTP Вот старый [топик](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892307/python-xlutils-formatting-info-true-not-yet-implemented). Что то изменилось с тех пор?